# Check if multiple points lies in multiple circles

Tags: c++, math, geometry

I have this math problem which requires to find if a point lies in all the circles... I have almost all the code but it has one problem that is it checks which point lies in each circle and not if one point lies in all circles.. I think I need to do a minor change but I can't figure it out...

```
#include<iostream>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<math.h>
 
int main()
{
    using namespace std;
 
    system("chcp 1251");
 
    int k, m, c, ic;
    float x[12], y[12], r[12], xp[12], yp[12], d;
 
    do
    {
        cout << "Enter how many circles (1..12): ";
        cin >> k;
    }
    while (k < 1 || k > 12);
    for (c = 0; c < k; c++)
    {
        cout << "Enter coordinates of circles № " << 1 + c << endl;
        cout << "x= "; cin >> x[c];
        cout << "y= "; cin >> y[c];
        cout << "r= "; cin >> r[c];
    }
 
    do
    {
        cout << "Enter how many points (1..20): ";
        cin >> m;
    } while (m < 1 || m > 20);
 
    cout << "Enter coordinates of points:" << endl;
 
    for (c = 0; c < m; c++)
    {
        cout << "Point № " << 1 + c << endl;
        cout << "x= "; cin >> xp[c];
        cout << "y= "; cin >> yp[c];
    }
 
    for (c = 0; c < k; c++)
    {
        cout << "Points in circle № " << 1 + c << ": ";
        for (ic = 0; ic < m; ic++)
        {
            d = sqrtf((x[c] - xp[ic]) * (x[c] - xp[ic]) + (y[c] - yp[ic]) * (y[c] - yp[ic]));
            if (d < r[c] )
                cout << 1 + ic << " ";
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

I think I just need to change the `if`.. so if anyone can help me I would appreciate.

Comment: (0) (1..12) should be [1..12] since the range includes 1 and 12. (1) better naming of variables can be very helpful. (2) If you've got `nCircles` circles and a point doesn't satisfy the `is_point_within_this_circle(circle_params);` test, nCircles times, then it isn't inside all of em. Loop through your list of circles and check how many the point is inside. If it's all of em, yes. Otherwise, no. Obviously, all points have to satisfy this test in order for you to be able to say "each of the points lie inside all of circles."

Comment: @enhzflep Where should i do this "(0) (1..12) should be [1..12]" in the "for" cycles?

Comment: @luis - in the strings presented to the user. Specifically, lines #16 (1..12) and #30 (1..20)

It wont change the way your program works. It is aimed at getting the user to do as you wish. `(x..y)` and `[x..y]` have specific meanings. The first is all numbers between x and y, excluding both x & y. The second, is all numbers between x and y, including x and y themselves. You can mix the brackets too. (0..10] would mean all numbers larger than zero up to and including 10 (zero is not a part of the set)

Comment: Simplify `d = sqrtf((x[c] - xp[ic]) * (x[c] - xp[ic]) + (y[c] - yp[ic]) * (y[c] - yp[ic])); if (d < r[c] )` --> `if (hypot(x[c] - xp[ic], y[c] - yp[ic]) < r[c])`.

Answer (score 0):

after all if you allow to enter 20 point your arrays xp and yp should have a size of 20, another advice if it's not a school work is using the structers, for solving your problem this is the code for fix it

```
bool b;
    for (ic = 0; ic < m; ic++)
        {
            b=true;
            for (c = 0; c < k; c++)
            {
                d = sqrtf((x[c] - xp[ic]) * (x[c] - xp[ic]) + (y[c] - yp[ic]) * (y[c] - yp[ic]));
                b=b&&(d < r[c]);
            }
            if(b)
                cout << "This point lies "<< 1 + ic << " ";
            cout << endl;
        }
```

Comment: It helps but still doesnt solve my problem.. cause with this i still dont know which point lies in all circles...And thanks i changed the array size to 20.

Comment: change `b=b||(d < r[c])` in `b=b&&(d < r[c])`

Answer (score 0):

Testing *one* point against *many* circles:

```
bool inCircle=true; 
for (c = 0; c < k; c++)
{
  d = sqrtf((x[c] - xp[ic]) * (x[c] - xp[ic]) + (y[c] - yp[ic]) * (y[c] - yp[ic]));
  if (d > r[c])
    {
      inCircle = false;
      cout << "the point is outside circle " << c << endl;
      break; // this is not strictly needed
    }
}
if(inCircle)
  cout << "the point is inside all of the circles" << endl;
```

Once you have this working perfectly, you can put a loop around it to test many points.

Comment: I get this error  "Segmentation fault (core dumped)" error... Not sure why.. And think the inside and outside is the other way around.

Comment: @luis: I cannot reproduce the error. If you add a [minimal complete example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) to your question, maybe we can find the trouble.

Comment: yeh its weird.. if i run program normally it crashes but if i run it has debug it doesn´t...